# Bound of $D\exp$ in Riemannian manifold with $|\text{sec} M| \leq K$ and $\text{inj}M \geq i_0$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am reading "Riemannian Geometry" by Petersen. The following is claimed.

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with $|\text{sec} M| \leq K$ and $\text{inj}M \geq i_0$.

Then there is a function $f(n, K, i_0)$, such that

$\max\{\|D\exp_p\|, \|D\exp_p^{-1}\|\} \leq \exp(f(n, K, i_0))$ on $B(0, i_0)$.

For $\|D\exp_p\|$ I guess, we have to use Jacobi fields $J(t) = D \exp_p(tJ'(0))$ and then make some estimation with the Jacobi Equation $J'' + R(c', J)c' = 0$ using the upper bound of $\sec$?

Comment: Is that an exercise or is it something that the Author states without proof?

Comment: This seems wrong. On the unit $n$-sphere, we have $K=1$ and $i_0=\pi$. Whatever $f(n,1,\pi)$ is, $\exp(f(n,1,\pi))$ is positive. But $D\exp_p^{-1}$ becomes singular as you approach the point antipodal to $p$, so there's no positive upper bound on $\|D\exp_p^{-1}\|$.

Comment: It is something the author states without proof. It's from the 2nd edition p. 318.

Comment: @JackLee: How do we get that there's no upper bound on $\|D\exp_p^{-1}\|$ if we're only looking on $B(p, \pi)$?

Comment: @oac: See my answer below.

Comment: I finally got a chance to look this up. This claim appears in the first edition of Petersen's book (on page 299), but it seems to have disappeared in the second and third editions. I suspect he realized it was mistaken and replaced it with a different argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems wrong. On the unit $n$-sphere, we have $K=1$ and $i_0=\pi$. Whatever $f(n,1,\pi)$ is, $\exp(f(n,1,\pi))$ is positive. But $D\exp^{−1}_p$ becomes singular as you approach the point antipodal to $p$, so there's no positive upper bound on  $\|D\exp^{−1}_p\|$.

One way to see why that's true is by using Jacobi fields. Choose two orthonormal tangent vectors $v,w$ at $p$. There's a Jacobi field $J$ along the geodesic $\gamma_v$ that satisfies $J(0)=0$ and $D_tJ(0)=w$ (e.g., see my *Intro to Riemannian Manifolds*, Prop. 10.10). Then $D(\exp_p)|_{\pi v}(w) = J(\pi)=0$ (see the proof of Prop. 10.20 in *IRM*). If we let $x_t = D(\exp_p)|_{tv}(w)$, this means that as $t\nearrow\pi$, $\|x_t\|\to 0$, and therefore $\|D(\exp_p^{-1})|_{\exp_p(tv)}(x_t)\|/\|x_t\|= \|w\|/\|x_t\| \to \infty$, and thus the operator norm of $D(\exp_p^{-1})$ increases without bound. Any other norm is equivalent to this one.